# Vk API: прикрепление изображения для комментария в обсуждении групп

Tags: android, vkontakte-api, kotlin

Как прикрепить изображение в Android через SDK, чтобы отправить его в комментарии обсуждения?

Я пробую делать так:

```
VKApi.uploadMessagesPhotoRequest(File(selectedimg)).executeWithListener(object : VKRequest.VKRequestListener() {
            override fun onComplete(response: VKResponse?) {
                super.onComplete(response)                    
                val responseString = JSONObject(response!!.responseString).getJSONArray("response").getJSONObject(0)
                val owner_id = responseString.optInt("owner_id")
                val media_id = responseString.optInt("id")
                attachments.add("photo" + owner_id + "_" + media_id)
            }

        })
```

и отправляю так:

```
val vkParams = VKParameters()
    vkParams.put(VKApiConst.GROUP_ID, group_id)
    vkParams.put("topic_id", topic_id)
    vkParams.put("message", text)
    vkParams.put("attachments", attachments.joinToString())
    vkParams.put("guid", messageId.toString())

    VKRequest("board.createComment", vkParams).executeWithListener(object : VKRequest.VKRequestListener() {
        override fun onComplete(response: VKResponse?) {
            super.onComplete(response)

        }

    })
```

В ответ приходит response:

1. с нулевым идентификатором сообщения; и сообщение не отправляется (если отправляю без текста),
2. с идентификатором сообщения; и сообщение отправляется без изображения (если отправляю с текстом).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Необходимо использовать метод **uploadWallPhotoRequest**

```
 VKApi.uploadWallPhotoRequest(File(selectedimg),0, group_id).executeWithListener(object : VKRequest.VKRequestListener() {
            override fun onComplete(response: VKResponse) {
                super.onComplete(response)

                val photoModel = (response.parsedModel as VKPhotoArray)[0]

                attachments.add(VKApiConst.PHOTO + photoModel.owner_id + "_" + photoModel.id)
            }


        })
```

также, необходимо при отправке параметра "attachments" в разделителе использовать именно ",", а не ", ":

```
 val vkParams = VKParameters()
    vkParams.put(VKApiConst.GROUP_ID, group_id)
    vkParams.put("topic_id", topic_id)
    vkParams.put(VKApiConst.MESSAGE, text)
    vkParams.put(VKApiConst.ATTACHMENTS, attachments.joinToString(","))
    vkParams.put("guid", messageId.toString())

    VKRequest("board.createComment", vkParams).executeWithListener(object : VKRequest.VKRequestListener() {
        override fun onComplete(response: VKResponse) {
            super.onComplete(response)

        }

    })
```